Angular 17 - Signal for a reference of another signal
I am working in a HomeComponente and I am pulling data from db for two arrays, I am using signals for storing my queries
aList = signal<A[]>([])
bList = signal<B[]>([])
my component show a list of my array items, and clicking a button the list changes, so I develop a ReferenceSignal, to only change that value and avoid duplicity
listReference = signal<WritableSignal<A[] | B[]>>(aList)
i want to ask, is this a good practice? how signals work internally if I have a signal storing a reference to another signals?
thanks


i want to ask, is this a good practice? how signals work internally if I have a signal storing a reference to another signals?

No, you are just nesting signals, unless you find a really good reason for doing this, you can do it a simpler way! we can use computed signal, which triggers a change, when the signals inside it changes, this can also generate what you need with less effort!
aList = signal<A[]>([]); // load data into signals at a later point of time!
bList = signal<B[]>([]); // load data into signals at a later point of time!
toggle = signal<string>('a'); // this signal can be used as trigger to toggle between the two signals a and b
listReference: WritableSignal<A[] | B[]> = computed(() => {
                                               const toggle = this.toggle();
                                               return toggle === 'a' ? this.aList() : this.bList();
                                           });

HTML
<button (click)="toggle.set(toggle() === 'a' ? 'b' : 'a')"> Toggle the views</button>


alright! I got it! I test it and it works excellent! (and its more easier), thanks!
